# Qmake cannot find my Android libraries because they have the QT_ARCH variable appended to the name

Tags: android, c++, qt, qmake

I have a Qt application that builds correctly for desktop. All of my libraries are dynamically linked. I'm currently building on Ubuntu, so they end up looking like "libMyLibName1.so", but building for Android outputs a library that looks like "libMyLibName1_armeabi-v7a.so", which is the original name suffixed with the QT_ARCH variable. I'm getting errors like "cannot find -lMyLibName1" and I suspect it's because the libraries are named differently.

I've read https://www.kdab.com/qt-for-android-better-than-ever-before/ and it looks that the suffixes are there to enable certain Android features.

My library .pro/.pri files all look something like this:

```make
#MyLibName2.pro

QT += core

include(../MyLibName1/MyLibName1.pri)

CONFIG -= debug_and_release
CONFIG += c++17

TEMPLATE = lib

HEADERS += file.h    
SOURCES += file.cpp

DESTDIR = ../../libs

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}

OTHER_FILES += MyLibName2.pri
```

```make
#MyLibName1.pri

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD
LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../../libs -lMyLibName1
```

What do I have to change in my qmake files for the libraries to be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the QT_ARCH variable to the library name in the .pri file when building on Android.

```make
#MyLibName1.pri

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD
android: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../../libs -lMyLibName1_$${QT_ARCH}
else: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../../libs -lMyLibName1
```